# Inverse using Gauss-Jordan elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, gaussian-elimination

> Assuming $x,y,z \neq 0$, find the inverse of the following matrix using Gauss-Jordan elimination.
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&1&1&1\\
> 1&1+x&1&1\\
> 1&1&1+y&1\\
> 1&1&1&1+z
> \end{bmatrix}$$

I started with this to find the inverse, but I actually don't get which row operations I should do.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
1&1&1&1& 1&0&0&0\\
1&1+x&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&1+y&1&0&0&1&0\\
1&1&1&1+z&0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: You need to use row operations that eliminate all the 1s in the off diagonal. It's Gaussian elimination, just for both the L and U triangular parts of the matrix.

Comment: If you show some attempt I'll gladly type a long lengthy answer. But to avoid doing homework help some attempt is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As a frst step, you replace the second, the third, and the fourth rows by themselves minus the first row, thereby getting$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 0 & 0 & | & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & y & 0 & | & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & z & | & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$Then, you divide the second row by $x$, the third row by $y$ and the fourth row by $z$, which will give you:$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & | & -\frac1x & \frac1x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & | & -\frac1y & 0 & \frac1y & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & | & -\frac1z & 0 & 0 & \frac1z\end{bmatrix}.$$All that remains is to use the second, the third and the fourth rows to eliminate those unwanted $1$'s from the first row. Can you do that?